# javascript add class to next 7 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to add class to next 7 elements of parent using javascript? I want to highlight next six elements after choice

```
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>list item 1</td>
     <td>list item 2</td>
     <td>list item 3</td>
     <td>list item 4</td>
     <td>list item 5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>list item 6</td>
     <td>list item 7</td>
     <td>list item 8</td>
     <td>list item 9</td>
     <td>list item 10</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

I read about :eq, :lt(index) selectors, but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: with your example, can you show which do you want to have a class? Add here the expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:lt` selector which will select matched elements with index less than specified number(Index starts from 0)

In this example, *0-6* `td` elements will be selected.
In case you want to mention start index, use `:gt` with the start index

Try this:

```js
$('table td:lt(7):gt(2)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>list item 1</td>
    <td>list item 2</td>
    <td>list item 3</td>
    <td>list item 4</td>
    <td>list item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>list item 6</td>
    <td>list item 7</td>
    <td>list item 8</td>
    <td>list item 9</td>
    <td>list item 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** If you combine `lt` and `gt` then it will work in order in which they are specified. In above example, selector will select `td` elements less than index `7` and then filter them out with index greater than `2`